# how to write this query correctly

Tags: sql, oracle

for each category show the equipment cheapest in this category
it was my attempts to solve it, however I don't know what to write further

```
SELECT category_of_equipment, name_of_equipment, price
from equipment
where price = ( select min(price) 
from equipment
```

the table

```
CREATE TABLE equipment (
    id int NOT NULL,
    price int NOT NULL,
    name_of_equipment varchar(228) NOT NULL,
    category_of_equipment int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT equipment_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Please share expected result you need to get from the query.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 1):

Rank equipment by price (partitioned by category) and return rows whose rank = 1.

That should be somewhat *better* than a correlated subquery because this option selects data from the `equipment` table only once, while correlated subquery has to select it twice (once in a subquery, and once again to return desired data).

```
WITH
   ranker
   AS
      (SELECT e.*,
              RANK ()
                 OVER (PARTITION BY category_of_equipment ORDER BY price ASC) rnk
         FROM equipment e)
SELECT r.id,
       r.price,
       r.name_of_equipment,
       r.category_of_equipment
  FROM ranker r
 WHERE r.rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  a correlated subquery

```
select category_of_equipment, name_of_equipment, price
from equipment t
where price = ( select min(price) 
                from equipment t2 
                where t2.category_of_equipment = t.category_of_equipment);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use self join -

```
select 
    a.*
from 
equipment a JOIN
(
   select category_of_equipment,min(price) minPrice from equipment group by price
) b
where 
a.category_of_equipment = b.category_of_equipment and a.price = b.minPrice
```